# Join Azure AD thru PowerShell script

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is it possible remotely join multiple workstations to Azure AD thru PowerShell script? I'm trying to find it but unable to find any documentation about Azure AD join thru PowerShell scripts.

Also, if we join a workstation using an Azure AD Global Administrator, will it be registered as the owner of the device? Should we have the user join their workstations to the Azure AD?

Hope you guys can help. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   No, currently there is no such provision of joining multiple devices to Azure AD through a powershell script. Also, remember and consider that the user ID that is used to join the device to Azure AD becomes the default owner of that Azure AD joined device. Thus, if you are using ‘Global Administrator’ ID to join devices to Azure AD, then it will become the Owner of those devices.

Therefore, to bulk join devices to Azure AD, you would need to create a Windows Provisioning package using the Windows configuration designer app and deploy it to all those devices. Please refer to the link below for more details: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/enrollment/windows-bulk-enroll

•   Also, to change ownership of the device to the user using it after joining Azure AD using the Global Administrator ID, you can use the below commands: -

```
$credential = Get-Credential
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $credential
Add-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner -ObjectId 9cfabe6a-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -RefObjectId 35b57bc1-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Remove-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner -ObjectId 9cfabe6a-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -OwnerId 2d2c5e37-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx ‘
```

Please refer to this link below for more details: -

[https://blog.matrixpost.net/change-owner-for-azure-ad-joined-windows-10-devices/#:~:text=Search%20for%20and%20select%20Azure,on%20Azure%20AD%20joined%20devices](https://blog.matrixpost.net/change-owner-for-azure-ad-joined-windows-10-devices/#:%7E:text=Search%20for%20and%20select%20Azure,on%20Azure%20AD%20joined%20devices).

•   Also, to allow users using Windows devices to self-join to Azure AD, please refer to the below Microsoft documentation link below: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/directory-self-service-signup

According to the above link, the users who have their email address registered in the Azure AD domain can join their assigned devices to Azure AD.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed info! This answers my questions.